# Retrieve name and image from database where image is stored as upload folder and reference is stored in database?

Tags: asp.net

Trying the following code but could't get the desired result.
I have stored the image in the upload folder and its reference is saved in database while storing the data in the database from the admin side.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;


namespace Admin
{
public partial class fetch : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string cs = 
  ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBSC"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spUploadImage", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


            SqlParameter ParamId = new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "@Id",

                Value = Request.QueryString["Id"]


            };

            cmd.Parameters.Add(ParamId);
            con.Open();
            byte[] Bytes = (byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar();

            string strBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

            FileUpload1.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64, +strBase64";


        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your problem statement and the sample code shown are conflicting to my understanding. When you store image in `Upload Folder`, why are you reading the bytes from database command query? Instead you should be reading the corresponding file name from database and then find the file with that file name from the Upload folder and return to UI, isn't it?

Comment: You are right , can you illustrate with an example?

Comment: Rather, I would like you to start changing your sample based on my explanation and post update if you face any issues. :)